# Composer Library not recognizing Laravel libraries

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-4, composer-php

not sure what's going here but I'm trying to install a library via composer

`gerbenjacobs/habbo-api": "v2.*`

When add it to the require array and then run update, i get an error saying:

```
  Problem 1
    - gerbenjacobs/habbo-api v2.0.0 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.21 -> satisfiable
by nesbot/carbon[1.21.0].
```

It seems like it is not recognizing the carbon files inside vendors, when I try and require Carbon it tells me it can't find Symfony/Translation which is definetely there

I have tried deleting my vendor folder then reinstalling everything but no luck. Not sure how to fix this, anyone have an idea?

Here is a screenshot of my terminal:

[image]

Comment: It recognizes it just fine, it just can't install that version of carbon.  Is carbon currently installed?  If so, what version?  You most likely have two libraries that require two different versions of carbon.

Comment: Possibly, is there an easy way to check my current version?

Comment: `composer show` will show installed packages

Comment: Ah 1.17.0 for Carbon

Comment: You can try updating carbon to 1.21 and resolve any dependencies that come up, but you may find that this version of habbo-api isn't compatible with your current setup.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it is, I get this now: https://i.gyazo.com/4cae142f0409be33c0d8a3f32bc6f1b3.png

I tried adding a folder to my laravel project, then add it to my class loader but that threw some errors aswell

Comment: Yes, this is saying that your version of Laravel most likely depends on Symfony Translation 2.5, but Carbon 1.21 requires a newer version of Symfony Translation.  Keep in mind, you can always check dependencies and other information by using `composer show -a vendor/package version`